Why does the conditionalPanel fail to work when using a bslib bootswatch theme version 5?
I am trying to create a simple application where the sidebar will change depending on which tabsetPanel the user is currently selecting. It works with R Shiny natively but when I try and style it with bslib, it starts breaking. I suspect it is a result of some Javascript or NS conflicts.
Additionally, it only breaks when I use versions 4 or 5 of Bootswatch themes. I have provided a minimal example below.
Why does the conditionalPanel with textInput id = "textInput2" not show up? If you change the version of bootswatch back to version 3, it works.
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

options(shiny.port = 8080)

# UI/Server for Module_1
module_1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel("Main", fluid = TRUE,
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          textInput(ns('textInput'), 'Enter text')
        ),
        mainPanel(
          uiOutput(ns('textOutput'))
        )
      )
  )
  
}

module_1_server <- function(id, session) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns

    output$textOutput <- renderUI({
      req(input$textInput)
      HTML(paste0('You entered: ', input$textInput))
    })
    
  })

}
# UI/Server for Module_2
module_2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tabPanel("Side", fluid = TRUE,
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          HTML("This always shows!"),
          br(),
          conditionalPanel(
            condition =  sprintf("input['%s'] == 'Test2'", ns("side_tabsets")),
            textInput(ns('textInput2'), 'Enter text')
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          uiOutput(ns('sideOutput'))
        )
      )
  )
}

module_2_server <- function(id, session) {

  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns

    output$sideOutput <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(
        id = ns("side_tabsets"),
        tabPanel(title = "Test1", br(), actionButton(ns("button1"), "Button 1")),
        tabPanel(title = "Test2", br(), actionButton(ns("button2"), "Button 2"))
      )
    })
  })
}

# Overall UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "cosmo", version = 5),
  navbarPage(title = "",
    module_1_ui("main"),
    module_2_ui("side")
  )
)

# Overall Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  module_1_server("main", session)
  module_2_server("side", session)
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Here is my sessionInfo:
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.3.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/Los_Angeles
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bslib_0.8.0   shiny_1.8.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] digest_0.6.36     later_1.3.2       R6_2.5.1          httpuv_1.6.15    
 [5] fastmap_1.2.0     magrittr_2.0.3    cachem_1.1.0      htmltools_0.5.8.1
 [9] lifecycle_1.0.4   promises_1.3.0    cli_3.6.3         xtable_1.8-4     
[13] sass_0.4.9        jquerylib_0.1.4   compiler_4.3.3    tools_4.3.3      
[17] mime_0.12         Rcpp_1.0.13       jsonlite_1.8.8    rlang_1.1.4     

I have tried redownloading shiny and bslib to see if it was a problem with the package installation.

bslib has its own page_* functions for generating page layouts which should be used in favor of shiny's *Page functions. Replace fluidPage() and navbarPage() with page_fluid() and page_navbar() and it will work.

library(shiny)
library(bslib)

options(shiny.port = 8080)

# UI/Server for Module_1
module_1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel("Main", fluid = TRUE,
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               textInput(ns('textInput'), 'Enter text')
             ),
             mainPanel(
               uiOutput(ns('textOutput'))
             )
           )
  )
  
}

module_1_server <- function(id, session) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    output$textOutput <- renderUI({
      req(input$textInput)
      HTML(paste0('You entered: ', input$textInput))
    })
    
  })
  
}
# UI/Server for Module_2
module_2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel("Side", fluid = TRUE,
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               HTML("This always shows!"),
               br(),
               conditionalPanel(
                 condition =  sprintf("input['%s'] == 'Test2'", ns("side_tabsets")),
                 textInput(ns('textInput2'), 'Enter text')
               )
             ),
             mainPanel(
               uiOutput(ns('sideOutput'))
             )
           )
  )
}

module_2_server <- function(id, session) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    output$sideOutput <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(
        id = ns("side_tabsets"),
        tabPanel(title = "Test1", br(), actionButton(ns("button1"), "Button 1")),
        tabPanel(title = "Test2", br(), actionButton(ns("button2"), "Button 2"))
      )
    })
  })
}

# Overall UI
ui <- page_fluid(
  theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "cosmo", version = 5),
  page_navbar(title = "",
              module_1_ui("main"),
              module_2_ui("side")
  )
)

# Overall Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  module_1_server("main", session)
  module_2_server("side", session)
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Thanks for the solution. It worked in the example code above, but for some reason, it does not work for my actual application. I do notice that the value for the side_tabsets variable is always "NULL" regardless of which tab I select. Can you offer some possible debugging steps?

Not really, I also had a look above and think that the issue lies deeper. I would need a reproducible, minimal example of your application where this behavior still occurs to see what is contained. I think this is also one of these compatibility issues of Bootstrap 3 vs. Bootstrap 5.

That is kind of frustrating. Okay, I can probably just use Bootstrap 3 by specifying that version in the bs_theme() call. However, I notice most of the other theme specifications no longer work (bg/fg/"navbar-bg"). Do I have to specify them in another way? Or were they just not available for that version?
